# Uniqueness of Moore Spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I am reading Uniqueness of Moore Space $M(G,n)$, $n>1$ on Hatcher, but I have trouble understanding one sentence below "...there is a map $f:X\to Y$ inducing an isomorphism on $\pi_n$." It is unclean even why $\pi_n(X)\cong\pi_n(Y)$ holds.

If the space is simply-connected, then one can invoke Hurewicz's theorem so that $H_n=\pi_n$, so everything is done. But I don't think we can assume that.

Thanks in advance if someone can help!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Simply-connectedness is necessary here (as indicated in the text). Google "homology spheres" (I think that it should be covered in Hatcher).

Comment: If you go back to Hatcher's definition of Moore space on p. 143 you see that $M(G,n)$ is defined to be simply connected if $n>1$. The reason for this is that without that condition, uniqueness fails. See comment above.

Comment: For a Moore Space $M(G,n)$ you want that the reduced homology vanishes in degrees other then $n$. For $n\ne 0$ this means that  $M(G,n)$ is path connected.